# Java Long Min and Max not exact as mentioned in docs

Tags: java, long-integer

As per java doc, the `Long.MIN_VALUE` is `-2^63` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `2^63 - 1`.

But `Long.MIN_VALUE` actual value is `-2^63 - 1` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` value is `2^63` if I compute it like here:

```
long min = -(long) Math.pow(2, 63);
long max = (long) Math.pow(2, 63) - 1;

System.out.println(min);
System.out.println(max);
```

Over all the range between minimum and maximum value is the same but the actual values are not. Is my understanding of the above code wrong?

My bad, its the way I checked that lead to wrong values. The following is the simplest way I could think of to verify 2 power values in java.

```
long num = 1;
for(long count = 0; count < 63; count ++) {
    num = num * 2;
}
System.out.println(num);
}
```

Comment: `long max = (long) (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1), min = max + 1;`

Comment: `double` can only exactly represent integer values up to `2^53 - 1`, and down to `-2^53`.

Comment: Apart from the 'pow is a double', if the MAX value is `2⁶³-1`, the result of `Math.pow(2, 63)` would overflow the calculation.

Comment: *"Is my above code understanding is wrong?"*; that would be yes

Comment: I'm not convinced about the `duplicate` mark here. They both have the same answer because the reason is the same but the question itself is **different** (*"This question has been asked before [...]"*). I found some meta-posts which suggest to not mark as duplicate. But also not enough to be convinced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.pow`'s return value is `double`.

`double` can only exactly represent all integer values up to `2^53 - 1`, and down to `-2^53`, because it only has 53 mantissa bits.

The error is simply in how you are attempting to check these values.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `2^53` as upper bound is correct in the general case, but a double absolutely can store the number `2 ^ 63`. The error in the question stems from `-(long) Math.pow(2, 63)` vs `(long) -Math.pow(2, 63)`.